# Swap divs when click on the image

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an image gallery where each image has a div with its name on it.
My problem is that when I click on the image, the div with the name disappears (it's intended) but I can't put the div with the tools in its place (div class = "ImageButtonsG").

Can anyone help me that when you click on the image, the div of the name will be replaced by the div of the tools. When you click outside the image, the tool div is replaced by the named div (back to the original state).

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vd63cm)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid second" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap" style="margin-left: 3px; margin-top: 13px;" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#modalPoll">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <div (mouseout)="img.showText = true" *ngFor="let img of data">
                <a>
                    <img [src]="img.src"
              class="img-fluid Vimages" (click)="img.showText = false">
                    <div class="VimageText G1" *ngIf="img.showText"> {{img.text}}</div>
                </a>
                <div class="ImageButtonsG" style="display: none;">
                    <a><img src="./assets/pin.svg" class="Pin"></a>
                        <a><img src="./assets/inboxpic.svg" style="cursor: pointer;" class="Inbox"></a>
                            <a><img src="./assets/chat.svg" class="Chat"></a>
                                <a><img src="./assets/taskblue.svg" class="Task"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an variable in the component to hold whether the ImageButtonsG div should show and toggle between it when clicking buttons in the UI.

```
showImageButtonsG: boolean = false;

toggleImageButtonsG() {
   this.showImageButtonsG = !this.showImageButtonsG;
}
```

And for the HTML:

```
<a>
    <img [src]="img.src" class="img-fluid Vimages" (click)="toggleImageButtonsG()">
        <div class="VimageText G1" *ngIf="img.showText"> {{img.text}}</div>
</a>
```

You'll need to add a similar click event to the tool section (or somewhere similar depending on how you want it to work) if you want to switch back to the text.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but it's not working :( The divs switch is not happening when I first click :(

Comment: Can you update your question to show the new code? Or create a stackblitz of it?

Comment: I implemented your code in my (post link ... stackblitz) and nothing happened. I solved the problem using javascript